# Use mutate with starts_with on columns and if_else

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I have multiple Tibbles and I would like to be
mutate them all with a function.
The issue is that the column names are partially different:
That is what I want to apply

```
mpg %>% mutate(model_QQ = if_else(year == 1999, 0 , if_else(cty > 20, 1, -1)))
```

But the tibbles have colnames like:

```
c("audi","nissan","subaru") %>% set_names() %>% map(~mpg %>% rename_at(vars(model:class), list(~str_c(.,"_",!!quo(.x)))))
```

I was thinking to make something like:

```
mpg %>% mutate(model_QQ = if_else(starts_with("year") == 1999, 0 , if_else(starts_with("cty") > 20, 1, -1)))
```

but these are working only inside the select function.
Any suggestions?

> EDIT
> I remake the code with case when, maybe is made more clear that way about what I'm looking for:

```
mpg %>% 
mutate(
model_QQ = case_when(

starts_with("year") == 1999 ~ 0L,
  starts_with("cty") > 20 ~ 1L,
  starts_with("cty") <= 20 ~ -1L
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```r
mpg %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("year"), ~if_else(.x >= 1999, 0 , 1)), 
         across(starts_with("cty"),  ~if_else(.x > 20, 1, -1)))
#> # A tibble: 234 x 11
#>    manufacturer model  displ  year   cyl trans  drv     cty   hwy fl    class
#>    <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <int> <chr> <chr>
#>  1 audi         a4       1.8     0     4 auto(~ f        -1    29 p     comp~
#>  2 audi         a4       1.8     0     4 manua~ f         1    29 p     comp~
#>  3 audi         a4       2       0     4 manua~ f        -1    31 p     comp~
#>  4 audi         a4       2       0     4 auto(~ f         1    30 p     comp~
#>  5 audi         a4       2.8     0     6 auto(~ f        -1    26 p     comp~
#>  6 audi         a4       2.8     0     6 manua~ f        -1    26 p     comp~
#>  7 audi         a4       3.1     0     6 auto(~ f        -1    27 p     comp~
#>  8 audi         a4 qu~   1.8     0     4 manua~ 4        -1    26 p     comp~
#>  9 audi         a4 qu~   1.8     0     4 auto(~ 4        -1    25 p     comp~
#> 10 audi         a4 qu~   2       0     4 manua~ 4        -1    28 p     comp~
#> # ... with 224 more rows
```

Or if you want them renamed `year_modelQQ` and `cty_modelQQ` you can do:

```
mpg %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("year"), list(modelQQ = ~if_else(.x >= 1999, 0 ,1))), 
         across(starts_with("cty"),  list(modelQQ = ~if_else(.x > 20, 1, -1))))
#> # A tibble: 234 x 13
#>    manufacturer model displ  year   cyl trans drv     cty   hwy fl    class year_modelQQ
#>    <chr>        <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
#>  1 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 auto~ f        18    29 p     comp~            0
#>  2 audi         a4      1.8  1999     4 manu~ f        21    29 p     comp~            0
#>  3 audi         a4      2    2008     4 manu~ f        20    31 p     comp~            0
#>  4 audi         a4      2    2008     4 auto~ f        21    30 p     comp~            0
#>  5 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 auto~ f        16    26 p     comp~            0
#>  6 audi         a4      2.8  1999     6 manu~ f        18    26 p     comp~            0
#>  7 audi         a4      3.1  2008     6 auto~ f        18    27 p     comp~            0
#>  8 audi         a4 q~   1.8  1999     4 manu~ 4        18    26 p     comp~            0
#>  9 audi         a4 q~   1.8  1999     4 auto~ 4        16    25 p     comp~            0
#> 10 audi         a4 q~   2    2008     4 manu~ 4        20    28 p     comp~            0
#> # ... with 224 more rows, and 1 more variable: cty_modelQQ <dbl>
```

---

**Edit**

With the updated information, this should do the trick:

```r
mpg %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("year"), list(A = ~1 - (.x ==  1999))),
         across(starts_with("cty"), list(A = ~ -1 + 2*(.x > 20))),
         modelQQ = ifelse(year_A == 0, 0, cty_A)) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_A")
```

Comment: This would mutate those columns. I would like to make a new one named model_QQ

Comment: @KGeles but you have two logical conditions across two different columns. Do you want a `model_QQ` for each column beginning with "year" and for each column beginning with "city"? See my update

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear enough.
I want to each tibble add a column with name "model_QQ ",
This column will first get 0 respect to one condition (that happens in the column that starts with "year") and then get 1 or -1 respect to another condition (column starts with "cty")

Comment: @KGeles and what do you do with these two values. Add them?

Comment: Nope, The new column, in the end, will have either 0,1,-1 values
It will be always the same name for all tibbles

Comment: @KGeles ah, I see now. But then, why are you using `across`? What would happen if multiple columns begin with "cty" or "year"? It seems that you could only rely on this if you already knew in advance there was only one of each column - is that not the case?

Comment: I know beforehand that these Tibbles have only once these columns but always with another tailing name.
I don't think I used across anywhere.

Comment: @KGeles I think your expkanation is clearer now. Please see my update.

Comment: Could you provide a small explanation or where to read more about this way with the list?

Comment: @KGeles if you type ?across and read down to the description of the `.fns` parameter, it tells you about the different options for how to pass functions to `across`, including the list. That's the source I use (as well as Stack Overflow of course!)

Answer (score 3):

We could use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
mpg %>% 
   mutate(across(starts_with("year"), ~case_when(.x == 1999 ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)), 
     across(starts_with("cty"),  ~case_when(.x > 20 ~ 1,  TRUE ~ -1)))
```

---

If it is to create a single column

```
mpg %>% 
   mutate(model_QQ = case_when(select(., starts_with("year")) == 
     1999 ~ 0L, 
      select(., starts_with('cty')) > 20 ~ 1L, TRUE ~ -1L))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 234 x 12
#   manufacturer model      displ  year   cyl trans      drv     cty   hwy fl    class   model_QQ
#   <chr>        <chr>      <dbl> <int> <int> <chr>      <chr> <int> <int> <chr> <chr>      <int>
# 1 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   f        18    29 p     compact        0
# 2 audi         a4           1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) f        21    29 p     compact        0
# 3 audi         a4           2    2008     4 manual(m6) f        20    31 p     compact       -1
# 4 audi         a4           2    2008     4 auto(av)   f        21    30 p     compact        1
# 5 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 auto(l5)   f        16    26 p     compact        0
# 6 audi         a4           2.8  1999     6 manual(m5) f        18    26 p     compact        0
# 7 audi         a4           3.1  2008     6 auto(av)   f        18    27 p     compact       -1
# 8 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 manual(m5) 4        18    26 p     compact        0
# 9 audi         a4 quattro   1.8  1999     4 auto(l5)   4        16    25 p     compact        0
#10 audi         a4 quattro   2    2008     4 manual(m6) 4        20    28 p     compact       -1
# … with 224 more rows
```

Comment: Sorry I had a typo and I edited too it should be starts_with("year") ==1999

Comment: I changed it and clarified better the expected output

Comment: Unfortunately not, is not what I'm looking for.
I added a case when which I believe makes things clearer

Comment: Thanks for the case when, very elegant way to make it!

Comment: It matters because it's easier to understand!

Comment: @KGeles i didn't meant that.  It surely matters to you.  For me, that is not the reason